# Clouwatch log insights query [replace UUID with *]

Tags: amazon-web-services, monitoring, amazon-cloudwatch

I have some logs comming into aws log group in **messages(field)**, I want to write log insights query to get real time count of incomming logs,
But I have unique UUIDs in each log that needs to be replaced by '*' so that. similar logs can be grouped together for getting correct count.
**I want the UUIDs in these logs to be replaced by '*' .**

Sample logs in system.

```
messages(field)

v2/documents/0003cfad-c6ce-46f1-b617-9efd95d79b52
v2/documents/0003cfad-c6ce-46f1-b617-9efd95d79b52/status/004083f4-467e-4d25-9d71-baf7087acb2b/
v2/004083f4-467e-4d25-9d71-baf7087acb2b
v2/documents/004083f4-467e-4d25-9d71-baf7087acb2b/status
v2/0063891d-6822-493e-a650-31cc57989310/create/004083f4-467e-4d25-9d71-baf7087acb2b/
v2/documents/00ee9bb9-e21b-44c7-b437-d0c7dd1057f8
v2/documents/00ee9bb9-e21b-44c7-b437-d0c7dd1057f8/status/00ee9bb9-e21b-44c7-b437-d0c7dd1057f8/
v2/documents/00fcce48-1768-4e89-a58b-e699be061ae4/delete/00ee9bb9-e21b-44c7-b437-d0c7dd1057f8/
```

Expected result after replacement-

```
messages (field)
v2/documents/*
v2/documents/*/status/*/
v2/*
v2/documents/*/status
v2/*/create/*/
v2/documents/*
v2/documents/*/status/*/
v2/documents/*/delete/*/
```

Note:- All UUIDs can be unique but follow same pattern of ---
[varchar(8)-varchar(4)-varchar(4)-varchar(4)-varchar(12)]

I have tried to get desiered result using  below query. This query uses **parse function** and relies completely on '/' as delimiter for creating new column, but this is not helping as all  the logs do not follow same pattern.
Ps: each of these is error log with **503** status code.

```
fields @message
| filter @message like '" 503'
| parse @message "* * * * *" as a, b, c, uri, e 
| parse uri "/*/*/*/*/*/*/*" as f1,f2,f3,f4,f5,f6,f7 
| parse f7 "*?" as f8 
| parse f7 "*/" as f9
| stats count(*)as Count by f5 as API, f9 as Call, f8 as call
```

Thanks in advance!!